# query by partial column name

Tags: sql

I have a 
Checklist table and 
there is 27 columns named "check1", "check2"..."check27".I would like to get all this values doing a query something like:

```
SELECT "check*" FROM Checklist;
```

Is this possible?

Which database? postgres, sqlite, mysql?

Comment: No, this isn't possible in SQL.

Comment: `select * from checklist;` ?

Comment: Are these columns constant or there might be more in the future?

Comment: You should consider normalizing that table to first normal form, since check repeats 27 times!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `select *` is not an option, the most flexible approach is creating a dynamic query. You will first need to get the column names and then build your query:

```
DECLARE @tableName as varchar(100);
SET @tableName = 'Checklist';
DECLARE @columnList varchar(300);

SELECT @columnList = COALESCE(@columnList + ', ', '') + sc.name
FROM sysobjects so
INNER JOIN syscolumns sc ON so.id = sc.id
WHERE so.name = @tableName
AND sc.name LIKE 'check%'

DECLARE @query as varchar(4000);
SET @query = 'SELECT ' + @columnList + ' FROM ' + @tableName;

EXEC(@query);
```

The ending `@query` should contain `SELECT check1, check2, check... FROM Checklist`.

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server, this is terrible but you could do it... Building dynamic SQL

`check%` being your `check*` in the `Select @columns` query

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(max);

SELECT @columns = STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + column_name
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
            WHERE table_name = 'Checklist'
                AND column_name LIKE 'check%'
            FOR XML path('')
            ), 1, 1, '')

DECLARE @statement nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT ' + @columns + ' FROM Checklist'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @statement
```

Comment: Why `nvarchar` in `CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), column_name)` instead of `varchar`? BTW, a specific max value is usually better than `(max)`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, was left-over stuff from playing around with it

Answer (score -2):

Troll ass answer...

```
SELECT check1,check2,check3,check4,check5,check6,check7,check8,check9,check10,check11,check12,check13,check14,check15,check16,check17,check18,check19,check20,check21,check22,check23,check24,check25,check26,check27 FROM Checklist;
```